Hive Metastore credentials on K8S
I am running hive-metastore on a K8S cluster (working with trino to query data on AWS)
I have configured a service account on the hive-metastore, and when I connect to the pod and run aws sts get-caller-identity, I can see that I am working with the correct role.
Working versions:
HIVE_VERSION=4.0.0
AWS_HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.1
AWS_SDK_VERSION=1.11.901

When I try to create a hive table, I am getting the following error
2024-07-02T06:32:29,371 ERROR [Metastore-Handler-Pool: Thread-223] metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException s3a://BUCKET/TABLE_DIR: getFileStatus on s3a://BUCKET/TABLE_DIR: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Proxy: null)

Also I have given the role very wide permissions, so this is not the issue.
The configuration xml (metastore-site.xml) for the hive-metastore is as follows
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

Is this the correct configuration? How can I validate that the hive is able to assume the role?

Also tried adding fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key properties with explicit keys, and also tried fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn with the role arn.

When I SSH into the pod, I can see that it is running with the correct role and I can run aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME/DIR/ with no issues
